# Is the structure morphism from an irreducible scheme open?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be an irreducible (projective) scheme of finite type over $\mathbb{Z}$. Is the structural morphism $\pi \colon X \to \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ necessarily open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The morphism $\pi \colon \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb Z) \to \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ has as its image the closed point $[2\mathbb Z]\in \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$, which is not open.

Comment: Right! And if we additionally assume that $X_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is nonempty?

Comment: I would guess, but am not sure, that then $\pi$ would be flat and thus (given your hypotheses) open. Confer [Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CVT)